# Unity: Determining Plane's UV under the cursor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I have a plane object. This plane is fixed relative to camera (plane is camera's child and always facing the camera -- [Fixed Plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoHzh.jpg)).

This plane has some RenderTexture on it. Now I want to know, what UV coordinate is currently under the mouse cursor.
The following script is sitting on this plane object:

```
    //....
    _collider = gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>(); // Plane's mesh collider
    //....


    void FixedUpdate()
{
    RaycastHit hit;

    var p = UnityEngine.Input.mousePosition;

    if (_collider.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(p), out hit, 100f))
    {
        var meshCollider = hit.collider as MeshCollider;
        var rend = hit.collider.GetComponent<Renderer>();

        if (rend == null || rend.sharedMaterial == null || rend.sharedMaterial.mainTexture == null || meshCollider == null)
            return;

        var pixelUV = hit.textureCoord;

        pixelUV.x *= rend.material.mainTexture.width;
        pixelUV.y *= rend.material.mainTexture.height;

        Debug.Log("UV=[" + hit.textureCoord.x + ";" + hit.textureCoord.y + "]" + ", XY=[" + pixelUV.x + ";" + pixelUV.y + "]");
    }
}
```

But coordinates I see in the log are very strange. First of all, when I change aspect ratio in a viewport, point that had XY[51,466] in 16:10 becomes XY[95,464] in 4:3 and so on. Secondly, offset is so huge that I am getting UV readings even if mouse pointer is nowhere near this plane.
I can't figure out how to raycast this right.

How to correctly get these UV readings regardless of a screen size?

**UPD:**
I ended up ditching mouse pointer entirely. Code above actually works well if you hide cursor and just look at the collision detection. Now I am showing a really small sphere at the ray hit point, and when you move your mouse, this sphere smoothly follows plane surface: now this is my "pointer". It works really well, and even better than "real" pointer: my 3d-cursor actually follows object geometry. And as this sphere represent actual raycast hit point, precision is great.

I really like this workaround, but question is still open.

Comment: If you are getting readings when the mouse pointer is nowhere near the plane, then I'd suggest fixing that first; this means that a raycast is still hitting the collider. It looks like you're making your own UI implementation; have you considered using a UI instead of rolling your own?

Comment: I am using PowerUI in FlatUI mode, this allows me to design UI in html/css easily. FlatUI mode means that it can render UI into the RenderTexture, so I can use it on some 3D models (like this PDA screen for example). This approach is normal for FlatUI, and in order to interact with elements on this html page, I need to provide PowerUI with a raycast hit result, so it can tell me which html element is under the cursor now. The problem is -- I cannot figure out how to make a 'correct' raycast that will be in sync with mouse cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `RaycastHit.textureCoord`. ([Link for Reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html))

You can get a `RaycastHit`-object using somethin like this:

```
    ...
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100))
    {
        //use hit.textureCoord here
    }
   ...
```

[Source](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)

Hope that helps.